# Using metal C++ with swift?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, metal

So, I've been playing about with metal C++ on iOS, and would also like to do a bit of playing around with swiftUI as well. I'm having a little trouble seeing how it will all connect up together.

I had originally assumed that I could create an MTK::View in C++, and that should be reasonably easy to connect up to swift *(i.e. use the C++ view within the App)*, but I seem to be wrong on that assumption. I've tried enabling C++/Swift interoperability, However if I attempt to pass an MTK::View into swift, e.g.

```cpp
MTK::View* exportedFunc();
```

Then swift just sees that as an OpaquePointer, and I can't see a way to convert that to the swift type `MTKView`. I pretty much have the same problem attempting to go the other way *(e.g. pass a device from swift to C++?)*

Is this a situation where you'd still need to bridge via Objective-C ? *(And if so, are there any simple examples available somewhere on how to do this with metalcpp?)*

Am I just going about this all wrong *(and I should be maybe doing everything in C++, and call into swift for the UI instead?)*

I've tried through C++/Objective-C inter-op, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I haven't worked with Metal C++ or tried mixing C++ with Swift, but I can say that C++ definitely works with Objective-C.